# test react container with enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have a container called "HomeContainer" that show us the menu and a list of users.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import User from '../users/User';
import { getUsers } from '../users/UserActions';
import Menu from './components/Menu';

class HomeContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: true,
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.initialFetch();
  }

  async initialFetch() {
    this.props.actions.getUsers();

    this.setState({
      loading: false,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section name="Home">
        <Menu selected="Home" />

        <section>
          {this.state.loading && (
            <h2>Loading users...</h2>
          )}

          {this.props.users.map(user => <User key={user.id} {...user} />)}
        </section>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

HomeContainer.propTypes = {
  actions: PropTypes.arrayOf.isRequired,
  users: PropTypes.arrayOf.isRequired,
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    users: state.users,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  const actions = {
    getUsers: bindActionCreators(getUsers, dispatch),
  };

  return { actions };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeContainer);
```

I'm trying to make a test of this container getting the elements inside. But I get a lots of erros.

```
import React from 'react';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import HomeContainer from '../../source/pages/HomeContainer';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

describe("Testing the structure", function() {
  let Component;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const user = { id: 1, email: 'aa', name: 'as' };
    const store = mockStore({
      users: [user],
    });

    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <HomeContainer />
      </Provider>
    );

    Component = wrapper.find(HomeContainer);
  });

  it("menu", function() {
    const menu = Component.find('Menu');
    expect(menu.length).toEqual(1);
  });

  it("section", function() {
    const section = Component.find('section');
    expect(section.length).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

The test's errors are:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

at Object.<anonymous> (tests/pages/HomeContainer.test.jsx:30:27)
at node_modules/p-map/index.js:42:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)


TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined

at Link.render (node_modules/react-router-dom/Link.js:76:35)
at node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:796:21
```

Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

Export your `HomeContainer` component to make it available for the tests:

`export class HomeContainer extends Component {`

This is in addition to your `default` export.

Comment: But, I have to export with the component connect.
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeContainer);

Comment: This is in addition to your default export. That can stay as-is.

Comment: For anyone finding this question and doubting this solution, this is exactly what the author of enzyme recommends:
https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/98#issuecomment-169761955

Answer (score -1):

I had this same error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined

I fixed it by using [MemoryRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/MemoryRouter.md). You can mount your component by changing the mounting portion to

```
const wrapper = mount(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <HomeContainer store={store} />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
```

Import the MomoryRouter from the react-router module.
For the first error, you don't need this statement `Component = wrapper.find(HomeContainer);`. In your test spec you can just say `const menu = wrapper.find('Menu');` You also don't need to use `Provider`